# Can a Google Colab session access files in another session's virtual machine?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm running two Google Colab sessions -- A and B.  In session A, I'm running TensorFlow, which writes to log files which are local to session A -- directory `/content/logs`.  In session B, I'd like to run a Python process (TensorBoard) which reads the files in the virtual machine running session A.

In session A, after I ran TensorFlow, the code below shows a directory called 'logs'.

```py
tf.io.gfile.listdir('/content')
['.config', 'logs', 'sample_data']
```

In session B, the same code shows just `['.config', 'sample_data']`.

From session B, how can I access the `logs` directory in session A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store files that you'd like to share between notebooks in Drive.

Here's a description showing how to mount your Drive as a FUSE filesystem:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA

Comment: This makes sense and is a simple approach.  I was hoping not to spam my Google Drive (or any other shared resource) with log files.  However, I will accept this answer if you believe that it is not possible for notebooks to share files.

Comment: Also, Google Drive seems to requires authentication each time I start a session, which is not convenient.  However, I see no API or other way to get at other Colab sessions, so I guess that's my answer.  Marking answer as accepted.